# reversing an array reverse the others

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

when i reverse a var b a get reversed also please some one can help me and thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Palindrome
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsPalindrome("tysui"));
    }
    public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
    {
       List<char> a = new List<char>();
       a.AddRange(word.ToLower());
       var b = a;
       b.Reverse();
       Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",a.ToArray()));
       Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",b.ToArray()));
       return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for b

```
List<char> b = new List<char>();
b.AddRange(word.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `var b = a`, you do not copy a list, but rather create another alias for it. Therefore, if the original list is changed, all variables pointing to it are now changed too.

If you want to clone a list, pass the original one in the constructor:

```
var b = new List<char>(a);
```

Please note that this only clones the list itself, not the contents of the objects in it. In this particular case it will not matter, because `char` is an immutable value type, but for reference types this might make a difference.